# Video chat with multiple usb webcamera

Tags: javascript, performance, architecture, webrtc, video-conferencing

I am trying web video chat using webrtc.
I checked webrtc, and It's a enough for this solution.
But, in my case, there are **three camera**(webcamera, usb camera) in one side computer.

```
                  camera1
 camera1    <->   camera2
                  camera3
```

So, I tryed Add multiple stream to one RTCPeerConnection.
But, webrtc is not support this.

I need create 3 RTCPeerConnection for this.
If I create 3 peer, then it seems like video chat room.

Is there another solution?

---

```
pc = new RTCPeerConnection(null);
pc.addStream(localStream1); 
pc.addStream(localStream2); 
pc.addStream(localStream3);`
```

Is this possible?

Comment: WebRTC absolutely supports multiple streams. What have you tried?

Comment: Could you share some info about that?

Comment: Your question is not specific enough to know what problem you're running into, and may be closed. Multiple streams should just work. If you share your code, I may be able to point out the problem and a solution for it.

Comment: The code you're showing is perfectly fine. Note though that peer connections today are track-based, for improved control like this, and `pc.addStream` has been deprecated, so it won't work on all browsers. Replace it with `for (const track of stream.getTracks()) pc.addTrack(track, stream);`. You need to elaborate on your expectations on the receiving end of this video triad, but in general: listen to the `track` event on the other side to pick up the different tracks and their associated streams, and assign them to the prerequisite video elements.

Comment: I checked `pc.addTrack()`, that functions can used for `add video`, `add audio`, I need add three video to one `pc`.

Comment: You can call `pc.addTrack()` multiple times to add as many tracks as you need.

Comment: Thanks @jib. That works well. And, I can add multi video stream to `pc`, On the other side, how I can get `tracks`?

Comment: Can I add `addTrack` with `camera index/id` to detect which camera mediastream(track) is added?

Comment: No, but the order of additions determine the order the `track` events fire on the other end. You can also associate them with different streams, and `stream.id`s *are* replicated remotely. Could you clarify your question though, so it is answerable?

Comment: This is my answer `pc.addTrack() multiple times` from @jib, How i can edit my answer? could you edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, WebRTC *does* support this, exactly as you show.

Except `addStream` has been deprecated, so you want to use `addTrack` instead. Or use a polyfill:

```
pc.addStream = stream => stream.getTracks().forEach(t => pc.addTrack(t, stream));
```

The order of additions determine the order the `track` events fire on the other end:

```
pc.ontrack = ({streams: [stream]}) => {
  for (const video of [remoteElement1, remoteElement2, remoteElement3]) {
    if (video.srcObject && video.srcObject.id != stream.id) continue;
    video.srcObject = stream;
    break;
  }
}
```

The above code will assign the three incoming streams to three video elements for playback, in order. The `track` event fires per track, so we check the `stream.id` in case a stream has more than one track.

Alternatively, we could have sent the `stream.id`s over a data channel and correlated that way, since `stream.id`s are identical remotely. Note however that `track.id`s are not stable this way. The third way is to correlate using `transceiver.mid` which is always stable, except it is `null` initially.